# Simplest way to inject google anayltics tags into arbitrary pages?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

I have a directory full of hundreds, if not thousands, of html and PHP files that I'm hosting for a client.  They currently include no google analytics tracking tags, but we'd like to add them -- ideally *without* actually modifying the files themselves.

What's the best way to do this?

I'd imagine I'd want to redirect all requests for *.html files to a PHP script, and have that script return the content of the relevant file with analytics tags added.  But that doesn't work as well for the PHP files -- I'd need apache to render the files normally, and then pass the output to my script.

Would [mod_actions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_actions.html) be helpful?  Is mod_actions compatible with mod_php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get a footer on every page, html or php or both... using PERL

http://stein.cshl.org/WWW/docs/handout.html#Adding_a_Canned_Footer_to_Every_

Answer (score 5):

I hate to come back with an answer to my own question so quickly, but it looks like PHP's [auto_append_file](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) directive will probably do what I want.

Comment: I'd use auto_prepend_file aswell to start output buffering, in the file you are appending you close the buffering and insert your analytics snippets right before </body> with str_replace()

Comment: Good call.  If you submit that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it (rather than accepting my own answer)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    # Add google analytics to .php pages
    php_value auto_append_file "/var/www/html/x.example.com/myFooter.php"
    # run html pages through php so the same auto_append gets applied
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
</VirtualHost>
```

Found the [AddHandler ref here](http://objectmix.com/php/444373-sethandler-php-parsing-pages-through-php-script.html).  AddHandler php-handler did not work.
Originally, I used a rewrite rule to pump all .html requests to a PHP script, but that broke things like requests for directories (which actually request index.html).